# Turn JSON into table pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a table from my json so that there are two columns 'ask' and 'bid' with the data from the arrays in each row. Right now its just making four rows with numbers 1 - ∞.

```js
jsondata =   {
            "ask": [
                350.5,
                346,
                341,
                336,
                331
            ],
            "bid": [
                346,
                341,
                336,
                331,
                326.5
            ]
        }
    
        for (var i in jsondata) {
                var table = document.getElementById("apps");
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                var td = document.createElement("td");
        
                for (var key in jsondata[i]) {
                  var txt = document.createTextNode(key);
                  td.appendChild(txt);
                  tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
              }
```

```html
<div>
            <table id="apps"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is data in inner for loop?

Comment: It was a typo, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to loop through the asks and bids simultaneously, and add a `<td>` for each of them to the row:

```js
jsondata = {
    ask: [350.5, 346, 341, 336, 331],
    bid: [346, 341, 336, 331, 326.5],
};

const asks = jsondata["ask"];
const bids = jsondata["bid"];

const table = document.getElementById("apps");

for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(asks.length, bids.length); i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr"); // New row

    // Add the ask:
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var txt = document.createTextNode(asks[i]);
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    // Add the bid:
    td = document.createElement("td");
    txt = document.createTextNode(bids[i]);
    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    table.appendChild(tr); // Add this row to the table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the for in statement for the inner for loop also.
The for-in statement used over an array will give the key as array indexes not the value i.e 0,1,2.

Use for-of loop to get the elements of the array rather than indexes

```
for (const i in jsondata) {
  const table = document.getElementById("apps");
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  const td = document.createElement("td");

    for (const key of jsondata[i]) {
      const txt = document.createTextNode(key);
      td.appendChild(txt);
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use  [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) methods

```js
const
  jsondata =
    { ask: [ 350.5, 346, 341, 336, 331,  246 ]
    , bid: [ 346,   341, 336, 331, 326.5 ]
    },
  tableApps = document.getElementById('apps')
  ;
for ( let i = 0; i < Math.max(jsondata.ask.length, jsondata.bid.length); ++i)
  {
  let newRow = tableApps.insertRow()
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = (i<jsondata.ask.length) ? jsondata.ask[i] : ''
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = (i<jsondata.bid.length) ? jsondata.bid[i] : ''
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  }
```

```html
<table id="apps"></table>
```